# DoublyLinkedList. Does nothing when trying to insert between 2 nodes

Tags: c++, insert, doubly-linked-list

Im having a problem with my DLL insert function.  It has no problem appending onto the list but when i have a list of 5 objects and i want to insert in between the nodes it does nothing.  I have been looking around for hours to resolve this and nothing has changed.

Here is my code:
***Implementation in the main.cpp***

```
cout << "\n---------------------------Insert---------------------------\n";
        //Ask the user what position they want to enter the player in.
        cout << "Enter the position you want to enter the player: ";
        int insertChoice = validators.getNum();
        //Move the iterator back to the start.
        itr.Start();
        //If the position is NOT equal to zero, Continue.
        if (insertChoice != 0)
        {
            //Loop until the position entered is reached.
            for (int i = 0; i < insertChoice; i++)
            {
                //Move the iterator forware to this position.
                itr.Forth();
            }
        //Insert the Player to the position entered by the user.
        //list.Insert(itr,stats.input());
        }
        //If the position entered is equal to zero, Continue.
        else
        {
            //Append onto the list.(Add it onto the start).
            list.Append(stats.input());
        }
```

***Insert function in the header file.***

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Insert
//  Description:    Inserts data before the iterator, this works whether the iterator is backwards of forwards
//                  through the list.Inserts at the end of the list if iterator is invalid.
//  Arguments:      p_iterator: The iterator to insert before
//                  p_data: the data to insert
//  Return Value:   None.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void Insert(DoublyLinkedListIterator<Datatype>& p_itr, Datatype p_data)
    {
        if(p_itr.m_node != 0)
        {
            // insert the data before the iterator
            p_itr.m_node->InsertBefore(p_data);

            //if the iterator was at the head of the list,
            //reset the head pointer
            if(p_itr.m_node == m_head)
            {
                m_head = m_head->m_prev;
            }
            // increment the count
            m_count++;
        }
        else
        {
            Append(p_data);
        }
    }
```

***Append***

```
void Append(Datatype p_data)
    {
        if(m_head == 0)
        {
            // create a new head node.
            m_head= m_tail= new DoublyListNode<Datatype>;
            m_head->m_data= p_data;
            m_head->m_next= 0;
            m_head->m_prev= 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // insert a new node after the tail and reset the tail.
            m_tail->InsertAfter(p_data);
            m_tail= m_tail->m_next;
        }
        m_count++;
    }
```

***InsertBefore***

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           InsertBefore
//  Description:    This adds a node before the current node.
//  Arguments:      p_data - The data to store in the new node.
//  Return Value:   None.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------

void InsertBefore(Datatype p_data)
{
    //Create new Node
    DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype>* newNode = new DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype>;
    newNode->m_data = p_data;
    //Set up new Node Pointers
    newNode->m_next = this;
    newNode->m_prev = m_prev;
    //if theres a node before it, make it point to new node
    if(m_prev != 0)
    m_prev = newNode;
}
```

I dont think the problem lies int the implementation in the main but rather in the actual insert function.  Thanks in advance, Becca.

Comment: Yeah, Ive tried stepping through and testing the code still cant figure it out.

Comment: @MartinJames the reason im here is for help.  I have stepped through it and cant resolve it myself.  Im not trying to get someone to fix it i would rather learn how to fix it myself.  No need for the sarcasm. :)

Comment: @Becca - if you already did some debugging, why did you not tell us what you found?  You want us to go through the same steps you have already gone through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***InsertBefore***

```
newNode->m_next = this;
newNode->m_prev = this->m_prev;
```

you need to tell `this` to point (as previous) to the new node too.

```
newNode->m_next = this;
newNode->m_prev = this->m_prev;
this->m_prev->m_next = newNode;
this->m_prev = newNode;
```

---

This should also be

***Insert function in the header file.***

```
 if(p_itr.m_node == m_head)
 {
      m_head = p_itr->m_prev;
               ^^^^^^
 }
```

Comment: Just seen it.  m_prev is not of the iterator class but is of the node class.  Just causes an error.

Comment: It is fixed.  The problem was the insertBefore function.  Nothing was getiing relinked.  Your code fix worked.  Thanks very much @:) I appreciate it :)